# dmPermission property not working on discord.js v14

Tags: discord, discord.js

I noticed my discord bot commands were showing up in DMs too, which I didn't want. So I added

```
dmPermission: false,
```

to all of them. I refreshed the / commands and I can still see and run the commands in my DMs with the bot. How can I fix this?

Here is an example:

```
{
  name: 'setchannel',
  description: 'Sets the channel in which certain messages should be sent',
  dmPermission: false,
  options: [
    ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: How and where did you use `dmPermission: false`? Can you add some more relevant code, please?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros I edited my original post and added the object for one of the commands

Comment: Oh, so you're not using builders. Shouldn't it be snake-cased then? i.e. `dm_permission: false`?

Comment: Oh great, you're welcome ;)